# не прижимается к правому краю кнопка

Tags: html, css

как заставить прижаться кнопку гамбургера к правому краю? я видимо где-то накосячил, раз он никак нормально не хочет прижатьсяю

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 22px 0px;
}

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-container a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 20px 6px;
  margin-right: 63px;
}

.header-container .nav_link:hover {
  background-color: #FFFF66;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; */
}


@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .nav-menu{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
}
              //создаём гамбургер
.menu-btn {
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #223;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.btn span,
.btn span::before,
.btn span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; margin-top: -1px;
  left: 50%; margin-left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.btn span::before,
.btn span::after {
  content: "";
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn span::before {
   transform: translateY(-7px);
}

.btn span::after {
   transform: translateY(7px);
}

.btn_active span {
  height: 0;
}

.btn_active span::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btn_active span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-menu_active {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
}

.proverka_one {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px">
      </div>

      <div class="menu-btn">

        <a class="btn" href="#"><span></span></a>

      </div>
<div class="proverka">

      <nav class="nav-menu">

        <a class="nav_link"href="#">Блог</a>
        <a class="nav_link"href="#">О нас</a>
        <a class="nav_link"href="#">Главная</a>
        <a class="nav_link"href="#">Контакты</a>
</div>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        $(this).toggleClass('btn_active');
        $('.nav-menu').toggleClass('nav-menu_active');
        $('.proverka').toggleClass('proverka_one')
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя блок `proverka` не дает прижаться гамбургеру к краю, так как занимает место. Зрительно самого блока не видно потому что нет высоты и ширины а внутри себя содержит блок `nav-menu` с `display: none;`

Попробуй в `css` сделать так:

```
.proverka {
  display: none;
}
.proverka.proverka_one {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
}
```